# Why the output is showing 3 1 3 can anyone help me in this in C

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main() 
{ 

    int i = 1; 
    
    printf("%d %d %d",++i,i++,i); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You are probably refering to C but didn't tag your question as such. In JavaScript a similar line (`console.log(++i,i++,i)`) would have resulted in `2,2,3`.

Comment: See specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34536741/3386109).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program exhibits what the spec calls "undefined behavior".  This is not a valid C program, because you are not allowed to modify a single variable twice within a single statement.  A compiler is allowed to handle this however they want.  You will get different results with different compilers.  Some compilers might produce "3 1 3", some might produce "3 1 1", some might produce totally random numbers.

It's important to understand this.  Even if YOU can see how to produce a certain result, the compiler is allowed by the spec to do anything at all.

Comment: Interesting point, this clearly differs from JavaScript. Is it the same in C#?

Comment: JavaScript and C# both mandate strict left-to-right evaluation of expressions.  That mandate allows there to be an unambiguous answer.  C and C++ do not mandate that, which allows the compiler freedom to do more extensive optimizations, but it also means that some expressions have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

(not an answer, but further discussion)

It really seems like an interesting question (at least for me, as I am also a C newby).

I tried the following [snippet](https://rextester.com/ILFQ73353):

```
//gcc 7.4.0
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
int i = 1; 
printf("%d %d %d\n",pr(++i),pr(i++),pr(i)); // 3 1 1
i=1;
printf("%d %d %d",++i,i++,i); // 3 1 3
return 0; 
}
int pr(int v){
  printf ("arg: %d\n",v);
  return v;
}
```

And was shown (for the upper case)

```
arg: 1
arg: 1
arg: 3
```

I still don't understand why my two `printf()` statements yield different results.

Comment: The C standard says about **Expressions** that the evaluations of the actual parameters of a function call are _unsequenced_. _If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undeﬁned._

Comment: Right.  When you look at that first printf, you have probably decided in your mind which of those pr() calls will be made first.  The C and C++ standards do not dictate that.  Many stack-based compilers start evaluating the last parameters first, because they have to go on the stack first.  That's what you're seeing here.

Comment: As mentioned before, my post was never meant to be an "answer" but simply another demonstration that the processing order of the arguments is "undefined". I _do_ get the point now, obviously. I will gladly pay the price of the downvote for it and hope it will help other readers. ;-)